# How to change custom dom by select box when use jquery datatables

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I have a simple code:

```
<div class="table-actions-wrapper">
   <select class="table-group-action-input form-control">
      <option value="">Sort By</option>
      <option value="desc">Date Highest</option>
      <option value="asc">Date Lowest</option>
   </select>
</div>
<table id="datatable"></table>
```

My result:
[image: Change]

This is my dom in datatables

```
"dom": "<'row'<'col-md-8 col-sm-12'l><'col-md-4 col-sm-12'f>t<'row'<'col-md-5 col-sm-12'i><'col-md-7 col-sm-12'p>>",
```

=> How to change input filter by select box "sort by" on top right table. Any ideas ?

[image: Result]

Comment: Did the solution below fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

You could possibly use the following procedure (rather than trying to customise the `dom` property of the data table too much):

1. Wait for the data table to initialise (and be populated with data)
2. Move the existing `div.table-actions-wrapper` into the correct place in the data table DOM

### Example

**Data table `dom` property (added an ID and removed the search field):**

```
"dom": "<'row'<'col-md-8 col-sm-12'l><'#customSort.col-md-4 col-sm-12'>t<'row'<'col-md-5 col-sm-12'i><'col-md-7 col-sm-12'p>>",
```

**jQuery to move the custom sort drop-down list into place:**

```
$('#datatable').on('init.dt', function () {
    var customSort = $('.table-actions-wrapper').detach();
    customSort.appendTo('#customSort');
});
```